# Selection-sort on nodes - java

Tags: java, sorting, nodes, selection-sort

I am currently trying to code a selection sort for nodes in java.
I also coded a bubble sort which works perfect, but for some reason the selection sort does not work. I am very new to java, so excuse me for not finding the mistake.

My selection sort actually sorts everything. The result is fine. But the execution is not how a selection sort should work.

First I switched the Nodes instead of the value, it worked but not as it should. So I came up with the solution of leaving the Node where it is and just switch the value.

```
public void selectionSort() {
    for (IntegerNode i = first; i != null; i = i.nextNode) {
        for (IntegerNode j = i.nextNode; j != null; j = j.nextNode) {
            if (i.value > j.value) {
                int temp = i.value;
                i.value = j.value;
                j.value = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the first time it actually does what it should do. It switches the places. But after that it takes the smallest int and puts it in front of the bigger int, instead of switching it. I'll show you an example output

Unsorted:

```
2, 9, 7, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8,
```

Starting to sort:

```
1, 9, 7, 6, 3, 2, 5, 8,
1, 2, 9, 7, 6, 3, 5, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 9, 7, 6, 5, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 6, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

Sorted:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

// You can see at row 1 - it switches 2 with the 5, exactly what a selection-sort should do.
// 2nd row +  - it just takes the small ints and put it infront of the bigger ints.

It's my first question, I hope I gave enough code. If you need more just add a comment! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try walking through your data set with your algorithm.

Basically the issue you are seeing is that the value of i will always be swapped with the next element j if j is smaller than i's current value.

so in your line 1 of starting to sort (i=1, j=2):

9>7 -> swap these: 1, **9**, **7**, 6, 3, 2, 5, 8, -> 1, **7**, **9**, 6, 3, 2, 5, 8,

7>6 -> swap these: 1, **7**, 9, **6**, 3, 2, 5, 8, -> 1, **6**, 9, **7**, 3, 2, 5, 8

6>3 -> swap these: 1, **6**, 9, 7, **3**, 2, 5, 8 -> 1, **3**, 9, 7, **6**, 2, 5, 8

3>2 -> swap these: 1, **3**, 9, 7, 6, **2**, 5, 8 -> 1, **2**, 9, 7, 6, **3**, 5, 8

no more swaps, increment i.

Instead, try to update your algorithm to swap only when you find the smallest item.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. I completly messed up the selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

I used the selection-sort wrong. A basic mistake.. For those curious how it looks correct:

```
public void selectionSort() {
    for( IntegerNode i = first; i != null; i = i.nextNode){
        IntegerNode smallestElement = i;
        for ( IntegerNode j = i.nextNode; j != null; j = j.nextNode){
            if(smallestElement.value > j.value){
                smallestElement = j;
            }               
        }
        int temp = i.value;
        i.value = smallestElement.value;
        smallestElement.value = temp;
    }
}
```